# checkboxes central vertical alignment using angular, bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, alignment

I am trying to center align my checkboxes, when you add a new input this is how they are displayed now:
[checkboxes not aligned well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdr1I.png) .
This is the code I am using (angular and bootstrap):

```
<div  class="container text-center">
<form ng-submit="todoAdd()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="todoInput" size="50" placeholder="Add New">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add New">
</form>

<br>

<div ng-repeat="x in todoList">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.done"> <span ng-bind="x.todoText"></span>
</div>

<p><button ng-click="remove()">Remove marked</button></p>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('todoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.todoList = [{todoText:'Clean House', done:false}];

    $scope.todoAdd = function() {
        $scope.todoList.push({todoText:$scope.todoInput, done:false});
        $scope.todoInput = "";
    };

    $scope.remove = function() {
        var oldList = $scope.todoList;
        $scope.todoList = [];
        angular.forEach(oldList, function(x) {
            if (!x.done) $scope.todoList.push(x);
        });
    };
});
</script>
```

I am wondering is there any way to align the boxes vertically (in the center of the page) maybe with bootstrap or any other suggestion would be helpful? This is my first question so I apologize in advance if it's not formulated right, and I thank you in advance for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure css topic, you should use a flexbox:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in todoList" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; align-items: center">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.done"> <span style="flex: 1" ng-bind="x.todoText"></span>
</div>
```

or in classes:

```
.flex-container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 align-items: center;
}

.flex-fill {
 flex: 1;
}
```

and set the container to the repeat div, and the fill class on the label.
fyi: flex: 1 means that the element should fill up the remaining width of the container.
(I hope the code above has a proper syntax)

In bootstrap it should be something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in todoList" class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" ng-bind="x.todoText">
      <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" ng-model="x.done"> 
  </label>
</div>
```

but I'm not quite sure if this is a 100% correct